# How to configure Angular application for multi language support

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I did my research on the internet and my code is working as expected but I'm getting a console error. Here is my code:

**src/assets/i18n/en-us.json**

```
{
    "home": {
        "helloWorld": "Hello Wrold! I'm back",
        "greet": "I'm fine. Thank you. How are you?"
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
HttpClientModule,
TranslateModule.forRoot( {
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader, useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => { return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/','.json')},
          deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  }
)
```

**Logic**

```
supportLanguages =['en-us', 'en-uk', 'en-in', 'en-aus'];

constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { 
  this.translateService.addLangs(this.supportLanguages);
  this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en-us');

  const browserLang = this.translateService.getBrowserLang();
  this.translateService.use(browserLang);
}
```

**Template**

```
<span class="first">{{'home.helloWorld' | translate}}</span>
<span class="first">{{'home.greet' | translate}}</span>
```

Code is working but why this console error is there. This will fail my unit tests also I suppose.

> GEThttp://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/en.json
> [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]

> ERROR
> Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/en.json", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/en.json: 404 Not Found", error: "\n<html lang="en">\n\n<meta charset="utf-8">\nError\n\n\n
>
> ```
> Cannot GET /assets/i18n/en.json
> ```
>
> \n\n\n" }

My browser language is also en-us:

[image]

Please point out my mistake

Comment: Your translation file is en-us.json but actual requested file is en.json. either rename that or change the used language to en-us

Comment: @JelleBruisten, It should not invoke e.json. My browser language is alo en-us. See I've added one screenshot just now.

Comment: @tanzeel in your asset folder where is en.json file ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, the path is _src/assets/i18n/en-us.json_

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, i dont have _en.json_. i have _en-us.json_ and i want this also.

Comment: @tenzeel you need to provide asset folder outside of src  and give path of asset in http like (asset/..)

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, i believe you are an indian. if yes then we are on same tim zone. can we have a zoom call?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, no no bro. cannot change the folder structure for this reason

Comment: @Tanzeel Can you show small demo where I can see this error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232445/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-tanzeel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this code in your app.component.ts..

```
this.translateService.use(navigator.language);
```

The problem is your was passing different language file to .use() method, which is not at present in asset folder. So you need to pass correct language code to .use() method.

`navigator.language` detects current browser language and gives you code of that language. and now you are passing correct code like `en-US` and now your asset will match file name with `en-US.json` and your current `en` file not found error will remove.